# How to say "I have only one year left" in Italian?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I sent this to someone who mainly speaks Italian and there was confusion.  Left is translated by Google as "sinistra" which is not what I want, haha.  More like "partire" or "lasciare" but I'm unsure if these are the correct words.

Comment: “is translated”: by whom?

Comment: If you put this into Google it translates it as sanestra the direction left.

Comment: Are you sure? Even if Google chooses for “left” the meaning that is wrong here (that is, the one as in “left hand”), I'd expect it to use the correct word *sinistra*.

Comment: Sorry I did spell it wrong it took my awhile to realize what you were saying.  However I want to use a different left.  Like how you you translate "no man left behind"  or "one week left until exams"

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot really translate word for word between different languages. This is why it is so important to provide context for the sentences one is trying to translate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I have one year left: *mi rimane un anno*, *mi resta un anno*, *ho un anno*. Variants are *mi rimane **solo** un anno* (I have only one year left), *mi rimane **ancora** un anno* (I've still one year left) and *mi rimane **appena** un anno* (I have barely one year left). A more colloquial form is *ce n'ho per un anno* (literally *I have enough of it for one year*, it's akin to *one year to go*). Note that *avercene* is often used for the time left to live.

The form with the verb *avere* ("ho un anno") should be used with some modifier (ho **ancora** un anno), otherwise if you say *ho un anno* you seem to be saying you're one year old. It's still possible to misinterpret *ho solo un anno* as "I'm only one year old"; this isn't likely with *ancora*.

There are some special forms used in specific contexts: in the military you would say *un anno all'alba* - a year till dawn.

- no man left behind: *nessuno sarà lasciato indietro*
- one week left until exams: *manca una settimana agli esami*.

Answer (score 7):

"I have only one year left" would translate as "mi rimane solo un anno". Hard to say what's the best translation without the full context, though.